# React observable epic with Redux Toolkit and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-observable, redux-toolkit

I'm not sure how to write a React observable epic with Redux Toolkit and Typescript.

Suppose I have this authSlice:

```
import { CaseReducer, createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type AuthState = {
  token: string,
  loading: boolean,
};

const initialState: AuthState = {
  token: "",
  loading: false,
};

const loginStart: CaseReducer<AuthState, PayloadAction<{username: string, password: string}>> = (state, action) => ({
  ...state,
  loading: true,
  token: "",
});

const loginCompleted: CaseReducer<AuthState, PayloadAction<{token: string}>> = (state, action) => ({
  ...state,
  loading: false,
  token: action.payload.token,
});

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    loginStart,
    loginCompleted,
  },
});

export default authSlice;
```

and this store:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { combineEpics, createEpicMiddleware } from 'redux-observable';
import authEpic from './epics/authEpic';
import authSlice from './slices/authSlice';

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();

export const rootEpic = combineEpics(
  authEpic
);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authSlice.reducer,
  },
  middleware: [epicMiddleware]
});

epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export default store;
```

how should I write this authEpic (I hope the purpose is self-explanatory):

```
import { Action, Observable } from 'redux';
import { ActionsObservable, ofType } from 'redux-observable';
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import authSlice from '../slices/authSlice';

export default (action$: ActionsObservable<???>) => action$.pipe(
  ofType(???), /* should be of type loginStart */
  switchMap<???,???>(action => ajax.post( // should be from a loginStart action to {token: string}
    "url", {
      username: action.payload.username, 
      password: action.payload.password 
    }
  )),
  ...
);
```

I'm totally confused about the ??? that is what should be the types and how redux observable should be linked with redux toolkit.

Any hint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that redux-toolkit obscures the actions so it's hard to know what the action types are.  Whereas in a traditional redux setup they are just a bunch of constants.

```
type T = ReturnType<typeof authSlice.actions.loginStart>['type']; // T is string

// have to create an action to find the actual value of the string
const action = authSlice.actions.loginStart({username: "name", password: "pw"});
const type = action.type;
console.log(type);
```

It appears that the `action.type` for the action created by `authSlice.actions.loginStart` is "auth/loginStart" and its type is just `string` rather than a specific string literal. The formula is `${sliceName}/${reducerName}`. So the `ofType` becomes

```
ofType("auth/loginStart")
```

Now for the generic annotations.  Our `authEpic` is taking a login start action and converting it to a login completed action.  We can get those two types in a round-about way by looking at `authSlice`:

```
type LoginStartAction = ReturnType<typeof authSlice.actions.loginStart>`)
```

But this is silly because we already know the action types from when we created `authSlice`.  The action type is the `PayloadAction` inside of your `CaseReducer`.  Let's alias and export those:

```
export type LoginStartAction = PayloadAction<{ username: string; password: string }>;

export type LoginCompletedAction = PayloadAction<{ token: string }>;
```

These are the types that you'll use for the case reducers:

```
const loginStart: CaseReducer<AuthState, LoginStartAction> = ...

const loginCompleted: CaseReducer<AuthState, LoginCompletedAction> = ...
```

I'm not too familiar with observables and epics, but I think the typings that you want on your `authEpic` are:

```
export default (action$: ActionsObservable<LoginStartAction>) => action$.pipe(
    ofType("auth/loginStart"),
    switchMap<LoginStartAction, ObservableInput<LoginCompletedAction>>(
        action => ajax.post(
            "url", action.payload
        )
    )
    ...
);
```

Comment: Thanks, just one question: 1) is there a way to get rid of the string "auth/loginStart" and get it automatically from authSlice.actions.loginStart?

Comment: Yeah I hate hardcoded strings too.  You can do it by creating a dummy action and accessing its type, but you would have to pass a valid payload to create the action.  I just looked at this docs page https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript and it seems like there is a utility I didn't know about where you can call `loginStart.match(action)` to check if an action matches the type.  That wouldn't work with your `ofType` pipe, but surely there's a boolean pipe you can use to call that function.

Comment: Yes I read about the `match` function, however I kinda don't like it because it just checks the payload type and not the true action type AFAIK, so maybe if I have two actions with the same payload type I'm unsure about what it would do... However, I tried trivially with `ofType(authSlice.actions.loginStart.type)` and it seems to work, do you agree?

Comment: I would think it checks the action type?  But if `authSlice.actions.loginStart.type` works then yeah do that.  I didn't realize it had a `type` property since it's primary a function.

Comment: You where right, as well as @phry, I read the implementation and the `filter(authSlice.actions.loginStart.match)` does indeed filter the action type and returns the correct typed action, so that is the way to go!

Answer (score 14):

In redux-toolkit, you should use the `action.match` function in a `filter` instead of `ofType` for a similar workflow, as [stated in the documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction#with-redux-observable).

This example from the docs will work with all RTK actions, no matter if created with `createAction`, `createSlice` or `createAsyncThunk`.

```
import { createAction, Action } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators'

const increment = createAction<number>('INCREMENT')

export const epic = (actions$: Observable<Action>) =>
  actions$.pipe(
    filter(increment.match),
    map((action) => {
      // action.payload can be safely used as number here (and will also be correctly inferred by TypeScript)
      // ...
    })
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a read through the redux-toolkit docs and tried to apply it to redux-observable as best I could. This is what I came up with.

```
import { delay, mapTo} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';
import { createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const delayTime = 1000
export type pingValues = 'PING' | 'PONG'

export interface PingState {
    value: pingValues,
    isStarted: boolean,
    count: number
}

const initialState: PingState = {
    value: 'PING',
    isStarted: false,
    count: 0
};

export const pingSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'ping',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        // createSlice does some cool things here. It creates an Action Create function (setPing()) and an Action Type, with a type property 'ping/setPing'. It adds that string as ToString() on the function as well which we can use in the ofType() calls with rxjs
        setPing: (state => {
            state.value = 'PING'
            state.isStarted = true
            state.count++;
        }),
        setPong: (state => {
            state.value = 'PONG';
            state.isStarted = true;
            state.count++;
        })
    },
});

// Epics
export const pingEpic = (action$:any) => action$.pipe(
    ofType(setPing), // Pulling out the string 'ping/setPing' from the action creator 
    delay(delayTime),// Asynchronously wait 1000ms then continue
    mapTo(setPong()) // here we're executing the action creator to create an action Type 'plain old javascript object' 
);

export const pongEpic = (action$:any) => action$.pipe(
    ofType(setPong), 
    delay(delayTime),
    mapTo(setPing())
);
 

// Export the actionCreators
export const { setPing, setPong } = pingSlice.actions;

// export the reducer
export default pingSlice.reducer;
```